# Web Crawler - Fetching data from over 2000 web pages (TED web site example)

Tags: php, html, web-crawler

I am writing a php crone job script that will run once a week

the main purpose of this script is to get details from all TED talks that are available on the TED 
we site (for example to make this question more understandable)

this script will take around 70min to run and it goes over 2000 web pages

my questions are :

1) is there a better / faster way to get the web page each time, im using the function :

> file_get_contents_curl($url)

2) is it a good practice to hold all the talks in a array (that can get pretty big)

3) is there a better way in general to get for example all ted talks details from a web site ? what is the best way to "crawl" on TED website to get all the talks

**Ive checked the option to use rss feeds but its missing some details i need.

Thanks

```
<?php
define("START_ID", 1);
define("STOP_TED_QUERY",20);
define ("VALID_PAGE","TED | Talks");
/**
 * this script will run as a cron job and will go over all pages
 * on TED http://www.ted.com/talks/view/id/ 
 * from id 1 till there are no more pages
 */

/**
 * function get a file using curl (fast)
 * @param $url - url which we want to get its content
 * @return the data of the file
 * @author XXXXX
 */
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

//will hold all talks in array
$tedTalks = array();

//id to start the query from
$id=START_ID;

//will indicate when needed to stop the query beacuse reached the end id's on TED website
$endOFQuery=0;

//get the time
$time_start = microtime(true);

//start the query on TED website
//if we will query 20 pages in a row that do not exsist we will stop the querys and assume there are no more
while ($endOFQuery < STOP_TED_QUERY){

    //get the page of the talk
    $html = file_get_contents_curl("http://www.ted.com/talks/view/id/$id");

    //parsing begins here:
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

    //get and display what you need:
    $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;


    //check if this a valid page
    if (! strcmp ($title , VALID_PAGE ))
        //this is a removed ted talk or the end of the query so raise a flag (if we get anough of these in a row we will stop)
        $endOFQuery++;
    else {
        //this is a valid TED talk get its details

        //reset the flag for end of query
        $endOFQuery = 0;

        //get meta tags
        $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

        //get the tag we need (keywords)
        for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
        {
            $meta = $metas->item($i);
            if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
                $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        }

        //create new talk object and populate it
        $talk = new Talk();
        //set its ted id from ted web site
        $talk->setID($id);
        //parse the name (name has un-needed char's in the end)
        $talk->setName( substr($title, 0, strpos( $title, '|')) );

        //parse the String of tags to array
        $keywords = explode(",", $keywords);
        //remove un-needed items from it
        $keywords=array_diff($keywords, array("TED","Talks"));

        //add the filters tags to the talk
        $talk->setTags($keywords);

        //add to the total talks array
        $tedTalks[]=$talk;
    }

    //move to the next ted talk ID to query
    $id++;
} //end of the while

$time_end = microtime(true);
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start);
echo "this took (sec) : ".$execution_time;

?>
```

Comment: You can use curl multi mode to crawl the pages in parallel. You can also investigate using Yahoo Pipes, which does the crawling and the parsing for the specific data you want in the page.

Comment: Henley Chiu - can you show a code snippet for the curl multi mode  ?

Comment: I'm think here there are good example http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got a web crawler php example on github.com

if some 1 is looking for how it works

https://github.com/Nimrod007/TED-talks-details-from-TED.com-and-youtube

Ive published a freemium api on Mashape implementing this script https://market.mashape.com/bestapi/ted

enjoy!